# Creación de un array con un número de posiciones

Tags: c++, array

Estoy intentando crear un array en un .h pero me sale error.
Mi idea es la siguiente, defino una variable para indicar el número de casillas que tendrá el vector y seguidamente defino el vector (el vector va a ser de tipo datos que es un struct con varios campos)
En el .h sería:

```
int numero;
datos* array[numero];
```

Y después en un método del .cpp asigno valor a ese `int numero` y creo el vector de la siguiente forma:

```
array = new datos[numero];
```

Pero el problema es que me aparecen distintos errores al compilar y uno de ellos es el siguiente:

> error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘nombreDeLaClase::numero’ 55 | datos* array[numero];
> note: declared here 54 | int numero;

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: "*Estoy intentando crear un array en un .h pero me sale error*" ¿Qué error?

Comment: Están descritos en el texto los dos errores que me aparecen.

Comment: Lo siento, es que he dejado de leer en "*me sale error*" cuando he visto que el muro de texto no parece contener código ni errores. ¿Podrías publicar el código que te da error y los errores de manera que la pregunta no parezca un ladrillo de letras? Puedes mirar otras preguntas del sitio para hacerte una idea de qué es lo que los usuarios esperamos.

Answer (score 2):

`new` únicamente puede usarse con punteros:

```
datos * array = new datos[numero];
```

Sin embargo, en tu código, `array` **no es un puntero**:

```
datos* array[numero];
```

Lo que has creado ahí es un engendro:

- En principo has declarado un array. Los arrays, por definición tienen un tamaño fijo que no puede ser modificado (no puedes modificarlo con `new`)
- Los arrays, de acuerdo al estándar, tienen un tamaño definido **en tiempo de compilación**. Tu estás haciendo `array[numero]`. Como `numero` es una variable, el tamaño del array no se conocería, en principio, hasta que no se ejecute el programa (tiempo de ejecución)
- En el momento de declarar `array`, la variable `numero` no ha sido inicializada aún, luego el número de elmentos reservado para `array` será todo un misterio.
- `datos* array[numero]` intenta crear un array en el que cada elemento es de tipo `datos*`, es decir, un puntero a un objeto de tipo `datos`

Lo dicho, simplifica el código y te funcionará:

```
datos * array = nullptr; // Es preferible inicializar el puntero
```

Y ahora ya no tendrás problemas para llamar a `new`:

```
array = new datos[numero];
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación, me ha quedado todo mucho más claro. Una única pregunta aclaratoria, con esto estaría creando un array de tantas posiciones como indique la variable numero en el que en cada casilla sería del tipo datos, ¿verdad? Que es lo que buscaba yo inicialmente. ¿Habría algún problema en que el número de posiciones del array (la variable numero) no se conozca hasta que no se calcule en un método (antes de ese cálculo no se utilizará para nada ese array). Gracias!

Comment: @marmu si el número de elementos no es fijo (se sabe en el momento de compilar el programa), entonces necesitarás una variable para almacenar dicho valor. De donde venga ese valor es irrelevante. Lo único que debes garantizar es que el array no se crea hasta que no conoces el número de elementos a crear. Es decir, el array no se redimensionará automáticamente al cambiar el valor almacenado en la variable.